# How to configure JW player after doing wowza trancoding enable and create smil

Tags: jwplayer, wowza-transcoder

I configure the transcoding setting in wowza server , created smil.
Now I have to stream the live video in jw player , which we done allready without transcoding .
Now what changes I have to done repective changes I have done in wowza server.

for now I configure the jw player like this

```
playlist: [{
image: "/images/myPoster.jpg",
sources: [{
    file: "http://173.244.173.196:1935/vod/playlist.m3u8"
}]
}],
width: '100%',
aspectratio: "16:9",
```